# Can I pass additional params to the rails credentials?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, credentials

I have a file, for example:
config/credentials/development.yml.enc
Call for this file:
Rails.application.credentials[Rails.env.to_sym][:some_key]
Can I pass params in this call?

I need to do in file with credentials something like this:

```
development:
    some_key: its_my_key_with_params_#{params}
```

Comment: Have you tried? Note: I'm not sure you need the `[Rails.env.to_sym]` part as that should already be resolved.

Comment: @tadman But where in this call I can pass params?

Comment: You don't. The credentials data is just strings. If you need placeholders, define them like `%s` and then use a formatter like `creds % [ value ]`.